# Команда net use в файле-CMD

Tags: cmd

Здравствуйте.  Делаю cmd-файлик с подключением сетевого ресурса:
`net use o: \\nadia-book\d$ /USER:Администратор 12345`
Если это набирать просто командой, то срабатывает.  А если сделать cmd-файл, то при запуске файла выдаёт: `"Ошибка 86, сетевой пароль указан не верно."`
Почему так?

Comment: а если в кавычки его?

Comment: `Администратор` оказывается надо было писать по РУССКИ!!!! - т.е. "Ђ¤¬Ё­Ёбва в®а"  А Винда не может проверку юзера устроить... тоже мне... корпорация монстров!

Comment: просто в винды три разные кодировки:)

Comment: В cmd она KOI8-R - вроде бы, а в win+R она в Windows 1251. А третья какая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось всё банальнее - кодировка... в cmd она в DOS (KOI8-R - вроде бы), а в RUN+cmd она Windows (1251)
Соединить два русских языка ни как не могут (консольный русский и русский из GUI)!
Надо было писать по русски! т.е.: "Ђ¤¬Ё­Ёбва в®а", а я писал "Администратор"...
Давным-давно ведь admin назывался Administrator, а теперь Администратор.
Отсюда и траблы.

Comment: Нет, кодировка там codepage 866, она же Альтернативная ГОСТ. Это не KOI8-R.

Comment: И вот еще в чем вы не правы: в RUN+cmd кодировка по умолчанию тоже 866я, а вовсе не 1251. Отсюда и проблемы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Тогда мне не совсем понятно, почему я это всё делаю специально в файл-менеджере FAR, где есть кнопка переключение русской кодировки DOS\Win и именно приходится писать в режиме DOS русские символы, чтобы потом они стали кракозябрами, но зато рабочими кракозябрами?

Comment: Кракозябрами ваши буквы становятся только если вы зачем-то переключите кодировку на windows-1251.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый вечер. Я так полагаю у вас домена нету. Ошибку выдает потому, что не правильно сетевой рессурс подключаете через cmd. Там чуть по другому.
Правильно будет так (хотя я не проверял но я так думаю):

> net use o: \nadia-book\d$ "пароль"/user:"имя пользователя" /SAVECRED

[Тут описание от майкрософта](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287536/en-us)

Можно ещё через vbs  подключать шары к примеру

WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "O:","\nadia-book\d$"